# Почему после Б буква Е в слове "беседующих"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как бы "беседа"? Поэтому после Б буква Е. Но почему? Как объяснить?

Answer (score 3):

Беседующих - корень БЕСЕД, Е - непроверяемая гласная в корне, традиционный принцип письма, выбор Е можно объяснить с помощью этимологического словаря: беседа - общеславянское слово, разговор БЕЗ СЕДА (без сидения дома, вне дома).

Comment: Правильно, только по Фасмеру не "без сидения", а сидение ***извне*** (дома). Это историческое значение, не несет современного отрицания "без чего-то".

Comment: Не убеждает. Если полгода плохая погода? Или на дворе хороший минус, болтунов — на мороз?

Answer (score 1):

Бесед - корень, который надо просто запомнить.

Очень древняя этимология, до конца не изучена. 
По Фасмеру восходит к bez+*seda (сидение снаружи). Никакой предложной приставкой "бес" быть не может, здесь другой смысл "беz", ныне в языке утраченный совершенно.

Но это вам, видимо, и не очень интересно. Просто запомните, что слово словарное. Такие слова не поддаются пониманию с помощью проверочных и вопрос "почему?" некорректен. Так уж сложилось.

Answer (score -1):

В слове *беседа* «без-» — приставка (предложная), изменённая правилом правописания. *Беседа* (беседовать, собеседование, собеседник) обозначает процесс с участием беседующих, противоположный общению людей *без слов*. Когда едят (процесс важный, без суеты), уважающие друг друга люди помалкивают.

Беседа — разговор не во время еды. Об этом есть два абзаца в монографии Т.Вендиной «Из кирилло-мефодиевскго наследиия в языке русской культуры».